# Reading low level network data from an Android device?

Tags: android, networking, qualcomm

Is it possible to access to low level radio data like the phone's **transmit power and ARFCN** ?

Looks like Qualcomm is offering some debugging capabilities and they are used in [SnoopSnitch](https://opensource.srlabs.de/projects/snoopsnitch) to make some security analysis. This Android application generate some pcap files in which they store the captured trafic.

The thing is, many fields are, as you see in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBVU7.png), equal to zero.

Is this because such information are not offered by Qualcomm debug tool ? Otherwise, how can I get such data from an Android phone ?